# Woocommerce - "proceed to checkout" button takes to false page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When pressing the "Proceed to checkout" button in my cart, I reach another page than the expected checkout page.

However, on the woocommerce checkout settings it seems that it is being set correctly (See image)

[image]

(Ignore the direction issue as I my wordpress is not english version)

Can you advise pleas?

Best Regards, Tal

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I am not using a plugin but a mo file. I changed the theme but it sends me to the same url: http://localhost/WinStats/buywinstatfile/ . It is a url I have created it, but I can't recall where and how to remove it

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you for your kind assistance. Since my work was really at its infancy, I have decided to build the site again, and now it is ok.

Comment: You can post an answer, with solved problem… reinstalling. or something like that…

Answer (score 0):

Since my work was really at its infancy, I have decided to build the site again, and now it is ok.